# Preloading a SQL databound listview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I've been looking online for a while and I may not be asking my question right but I can't find what I am looking for.

I have a dropdownlist on a web form that is databound to a SQL select statement that returns 3 items. I appended the list with a blank item at the top so that I am not selecting the other options on page load.

I also have a listview that has a `ControlParameter` of the DDL.

What I want to do is when the page loads to have all items selected instead of none.  Do I need to set `Selected` to `True` on each of the items in the list and how would I do that if the information is fetched from a SQL query.

A snippet of the code with the queries:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDockNumber" 
     DataTextField="DockID" DataValueField="DockID" 
     AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDockNumber" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MarinaConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [DockID] FROM [Slip]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAvailSlips" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:MarinaConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [avilableSlips] WHERE ([DockID] = @DockID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="DockID" 
             PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Somehow this part of the code got removed from the top, so I am adding it for more information

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDockNumber" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="DockID" DataValueField="DockID" AppendDataBoundItems ="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected ="True" Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: `DropDownList` is single select control. So you cannot select multiple items directly. Look for other controls like `Listbox`.